# Access to the interaction of two three level factors on a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts, brms

Using a mixed model (either frequentist lmer or bayesian brms) I have an issue regarding an interaction in my model.

I have two factor variable of three level : condition (0-1-2) and Tps_real (0-300-600).

I am running a model such as  Tps_estimated ~ condition*Tps_real (condition|subject)

The output is

```r
Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             373.794     16.238   53.734  23.019   <2e-16 ***
Tps_Real300             108.218      8.681 9334.354  12.467   <2e-16 ***
Tps_Real600             229.361      8.677 9334.747  26.435   <2e-16 ***
Condition1                5.502      9.466  224.029   0.581    0.562
Condition2                1.419      9.791  192.651   0.145    0.885
Tps_Real300:Condition1  -16.972     12.250 9334.426  -1.385    0.166    
Tps_Real600:Condition1   -8.372     12.244 9334.564  -0.684    0.494
Tps_Real300:Condition2  -10.408     12.246 9334.333  -0.850    0.395
Tps_Real600:Condition2   -5.394     12.246 9334.587  -0.440    0.660
```

I know and understand that the model use the first level of my factor to make the comparison, so for instance the first line of the output Tps_Real300 give the results against the of Tps_Real0. The same for Condition1 that is against Condition0.

However, I don't understand why in my interaction Tps_Real:Condition I do not see the Tps_Real0:Condition1 and Tps_Real0:Condition2 which are supposed to be against Tps_Real0:Condition0.

Could someone explain me either why it is the case or how I can make this contrast appear in my model.

Or more specifically, do you have a suggestion to have my Tps_Real0:Condition1 and Condition2 referenced on Tps_Real0:Condition0?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same reason. Real 0 and Condition 0 are both reference levels, so they don't show up as main effects or as part of interactions.

There are alternate parameterizations that can show all effects, but then the interpretation will be different.

Comment: But here it seems that my reference for Tps_Real300:Condition1 is Tps_Real300:Condition0 so I am wondering where are my Tps_Real0:Condition1 and Condition 2. I tryed to just do Tps_Real:Condition insteand of the * but there the references does not make sense anymore (e.g. Tps_Real0:Condition0 against Tps_Real600:Condition2). Do you have a suggestion to have my Tps_Real0:Condition1 and 2 referenced on Tps_Real0:Condition0?

Comment: You don't see it because those are reference levels. That is, you won't see an interaction where either effect is at the reference level. If you specify, say, Helmert contrasts, then you will get all the levels of the main effects and the interactions,  Each is contrasted with subsequent levels. 

With deviation coding, you get every level contrasted with the grand mean.

See https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/